# Mimic lecturing on blackboard, but facing audience

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy, technology-in-education, lecturing

I teach mathematics at MSc and PhD levels. My preferred method of teaching is old-fashioned: talking and writing on the blackboard at the same time.

Why? Because it has many advantages:

1. *Handwriting:* imposes few restrictions on notation and illustration. (Complicated figures I could project from my laptop, but I have no need for this in my courses.)
2. *Flexibility:* whenever this is useful, it is easy to 'deviate from the script'.
3. *Natural speed:* it imposes a natural speed on the speaker. Preparing slides using LaTeX or PowerPoint and just clicking through them, I find myself proceeding way too fast.
4. *Parallel displays:* having several boards available for writing makes it easy to keep some text/examples on display on one board, while writing on another.
5. *Dynamics:* referring to information on the different boards allows me to move through the room, adding a more dynamic aspect to the lecture.
6. *Ease:* it is a low-tech way of achieving all these things simultaneously with easily available means.

The main disadvantage of this method is that I spend a significant amount of time of each lecture with my back to the audience.

**Question:** What would you recommend as a means of communication that combines the six features above (most importantly, the handwriting and parallel displays), but facing the audience?

Obviously, a low-budget solution would be appreciated, but my institute is usually pretty generous in investing in technology that improves teaching, so don't let that restrict you!

**What I tried:** Many things, including writing by hand on tablets (iPads, Digital Paper, reMarkable, etc) and projecting this in the classroom. Perhaps I haven't found the optimal device for this yet, but it often comes out pixly, delayed, and less readable than my usual handwriting on paper or the blackboard. Using a document camera to project my handwriting on paper. Works well, but can project only about half an A4 paper at a time to keep it readable for people in the back of the room and, like other approaches, has the disadvantage of not having parallel displays: it's hugely important to be able to keep definitions, examples, theorems from earlier on for easy reference.

Comment: Also posted at [Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/126740/64).

Comment: I see that your question at Academia is currently on the Hot Network Questions list, so since it is not appropriate to have questions that are exact duplicates at different sites, I think it is better to close this question here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is already asked at [Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/126740/64).

Comment: Makes sense.  Too bad, though, because there are some subtle differences with math - but it's mentioned in the academia question, so hopefully answers will be good there.

Comment: You can work with an overhead-projector, which projects on the blackboard or whiteboard, and write what you'd want to write on the blackboard, instead, on "transparencies" (which you'd be free to do in real time, and/or, with basic preparation ahead of a lecture.)  You can then face the audience while writing on/using the transparencies.